# Create a new `catcodetable` in LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, catcodes

The latest LaTeX versions incorporated the luatexbase package in the kernel. The package predefined a number of named catcode tables, which have now been absorbed in the kernel. These named tables can be used as the first parameter to a `tex.print()` statement. Is there an established way to create a new table? Can my method for creating a new table named `normaldollar`, shown in the minimal below be improved?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\makeatletter
\def\test@{test}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_gset:Npn \_test:{OK}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\ttfamily

\newcatcodetable\normaldollar
\begingroup
\catcode`\$=11
\savecatcodetable\normaldollar
\endgroup

\begin{luacode*}
  local normaldollar =  luatexbase.catcodetables.normaldollar
  local expl = luatexbase.catcodetables.expl
  local latex = luatexbase.catcodetables['latex-package']
  local verb = luatexbase.catcodetables.string
  tex.print(expl, [[ \_test: ]] .. [[\par]])
  tex.print(verb, [[ _test:^~~$\\\\# ]] )
  tex.print(latex,   [[\test@ ]] .. [[\par]])
  
  -- prints the dollar signs
  tex.print(normaldollar,  [[$a = 1$$$]] .. [[\par]])
  
  -- prints the normaldollar allocation number
  tex.print(0, normaldollar)
 \end{luacode*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly an answer would be here: `\newcatcodetable`/`\savecatcodetable` are the documented interfaces

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks Joseph. I was a bit confused, if this was the best method or rather use he l3cctab module.

Comment: Ah, well yes `l3cctab` does offer a few more things, most obviously that it works with all engines (just in an entirely different way outside LuaTeX). I guess for the use case you outline there's no real advantage, though.

Comment: @JosephWright  Thanks Joseph you always helpful